# Apache: Disallow external access to directories via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

The goal is to prevent anyone other than the application itself from accessing the items within several specific folders.

Having read through some of the answers, I have:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://app.domain.co.uk/*

RewriteRule ^(folder1|folder2)$ - [L,F]
```

I've placed the `.htaccess` in the same folder as `folder1` and `folder2`, but it's not blocking access from external sources.

I've tried forward slashes before the folder names, but that made no difference.

Also, we are using the `app` sub-domain, and we are using SSL, if that's of importance.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this rule as **your first rule** in the `.htaccess` placed in parent folder of `folder1, folder2`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://app\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(?:folder1|folder2)(?:/.*)?$ - [L,NC,F]

# rest of your rules go below this
```

Comment: Hi @anubhava, I've tried that but it doesn't work. Also, I've clarified the domain name; it's a `.co.uk` TLD. I tried putting a back slash between each of the two parts, but that made no difference.

Comment: However, having tried accessing a file from inside one of the folders while in application, the preview fails while and external access results in a 404 error.

Comment: We ran more tests and it's working (I'm experiencing some issues with the web browser).